# Text on a image

Tags: html, image, css, text

I am working on a project where I have to set the text on an image. After setting the text on image, I am saving the picture. But the written text on the image is not displaying after saving. I need that the image should be saved with the over written text.
Here is my HTML Code so far:

```css
    .image {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    h2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="attraction/a.jpg" alt="" />
    <h2>Good friends are like stars</h2> 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What code you have done yet? can you show us?

Comment: Try html5 canvas element. Read up and report back 

Comment: <!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
 Hello World
 </title>
    <style>
        .image {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%; 
        }

        h2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="image">

        <img src="attraction/a.jpg" alt="" />

        <h2>Good friends are like stars</h2>

    </div>


</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

If You are asking about cryptography you can head over to this link:

http://www.wikihow.com/Send-a-Secret-Message-Through-a-Picture

If you are trying to save a text on an image you can simply
 edit that image in paint or whatever image editor
 you have and do not forget to **Save** that image after editing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "save file", the browser will downloading it. So you have to change the image file. Writing text on it, will not work...

Comment: Then any alternate for this,what should i use ?

Comment: Use a canvas. You can save a canvas tag in the browser, too and there you can render text on it. (See answer from ne1410s)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by now you've probably found this out already, but here is a way you can use to achieve what you describe:

1. **Create a `<canvas>` element** and obtain a reference to it in javascript
2. **Draw your image** on said canvas, optionally with some additional styling and/or design choices
3. **Desecrate the canvas** with text using `context2d.fillText('the text', ...);`  Again, you can go crazy on whatever styling and positioning takes your fancy

For more info, see the [W3C Canvas Wiki Page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/canvas)

You are now free to Save As... and the text is incorporated into the file.
Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7Ls9m424/